# why I can not see my GitHub pushes as contributions in my calendar?

Tags: github

Lately I have been pushing my works to GitHub but my GitHub calendar doesn't show them in calendar. What might be the problem? I am using push --force command, is that why?

this is the error I get whenever I try to make normal git push but I could do push --force yesterday but it doesn't show up in the calendar although I can see the changes in the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjgKL.jpg)

Comment: Has it ever worked and now stopped working or has it never worked for you?

Comment: GitHub use the email address(es) stored in the commits to collect contribution information. This is completely up to GitHub: the only way Git comes into this is when you set your `user.email` setting.

Comment: it used to work. I think there is nothing wrong with that . I m adding the error I m getting from the terminal to the main post above

Answer (score 0):

Do you have private contributions turned on?

[image]

Comment: shall I turn it on? it was off and I think yesterday I turned it on

Comment: I checked again it is off

Comment: That's why? What should the option be?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but the option should be on if you are working on private repos and want to see it in your feed.

Comment: mine is not private. can you see the screenshot I added in the main thready? by the way I see my screenshot as link but yours is visible image?